# In Dygraphs, How to display AxisLabels as Text instead of Numbers/Date

Tags: axis-labels, dygraphs

I need to build a **graph** to show world's **population** by **region** and sample data would be

```
China           1,361,300,000
India           1,236,970,000
United States   317,148,000
Indonesia       237,641,326
Brazil          201,032,714
```

I am new to `Dygraphs` and I tried simple example on the same:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js"></script>

</head>
 <body>
<div id="demodiv" style="width:500px;height:500px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var data = "Country,Population\n" +
     "1,1361300000\n" +
     "2,1236970000\n" +
     "3,317148000\n" +
     "4,237641326\n" +
     "5,201032714\n";
 g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("demodiv"), data, {
     title: "World's Population"
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, How can I use `Dygraphs` to display country Name instead of numbers on `x-Axis`? Is it possible with `Dygraphs`?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the valueFormatter and axisLabelFormatter options. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html

The following example will print 'text:' inside the legend and the x value from your data.

```
axes: {
    x: {
        valueFormatter: function(x) {
        return 'text';
       },
        axisLabelFormatter: function(x) {
        return x; 
       },
    }
},
```

Example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JaM3S/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is what I was looking for and I have modified a bit as per my requirement. Please see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JaM3S/1/. But one issue I am facing is, in my local setup the sample code mentioned above generates x-axis values as 1,1.5,2,2.5 etc... instead of just 1,2,3 etc... Not sure if I am missing anything here compared to your example.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. Your local setup leads to floating points at your x axis, but in your jsfiddle it works?  

Maybe you use the rollPeriod or showRoller options?

Answer (score 1):

@user3020781 Those two options for the x-axis helped me as well, thank you!  I also had an issue with having .5 steps between the whole numbers, and found the issue was I had the chart set too wide and I only had 6 groups plotted on the x-axis, so dygraph was automatically adding the half step.

Couple solutions: 
1. Add cases in the switch statements for the .5 steps 
2. use the pixelsPerLabel option inside the x axis.  The default for the x axes is 60, I doubled to get 120 which fixed mine.
3. Make the whole graph smaller.  Mine are all set to be 1000px wide.

Both worked for my problem.  Here's the Dygraph code.  I commented out the case statements because I went with the pixelsPerLabel fix.

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    dataArray,
{
    xlabel: "x something",
    ylabel: "y something",
    title: "The coolest chart ever!", 
    labels: ["FR", "Avg1", "Avg2"], 
    labelsDiv: document.getElementById("labelsdiv"),
    labelsSeparateLines: true,
    width:1000,
    colors: ["#339933", "#990000"], 
    strokeWidth: 2.5,
    valueRange: [4, 5.8],
    axes: {
        x: {
            /*the space between grid lines on x axis: default is 60px*/
            pixelsPerLabel: 120,
            valueFormatter: function(FR) {
                var ret;
                switch (FR){
                    case 1:
                        ret = 'A';                
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ret = 'B';                
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ret = 'C';                
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        ret = 'D';                
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        ret = 'D';                
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        ret = 'F';                
                        break;
                    /*case 1.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;
                    case 2.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;
                    case 3.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;
                    case 4.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;
                    case 5.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;
                    case 6.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;*/
                }//end switch
                return ret;
            },//end of label formatter,
            axisLabelFormatter: function(FR) {
                var ret;
                switch (FR){
                    case 1:
                        ret = 'A';                
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        ret = 'B';                
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ret = 'C';                
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        ret = 'D';                
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        ret = 'E';                
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        ret = 'F';                
                        break;
                    /*case 1.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;
                    case 2.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;
                    case 3.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;
                    case 4.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;
                    case 5.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;
                    case 6.5:
                        ret = '';                
                        break;*/
                }//end switch
                return ret;
            }//end of axis label formatter        
        }//end of x axis 
    }//end of axis

}  );
```